# A good tutorial on importing classes/SDK projects into eclipse for alfresco extention dependencies

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

So I got this alfresco java class and it has these import statements for dependencies, like these below for example.

```
import org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies;

import org.alfresco.repo.policy.Behaviour;

import org.alfresco.repo.policy.JavaBehaviour;

import org.alfresco.repo.policy.PolicyComponent;
```

But being a Java/Eclipse newbie I don't know how to bring things like `org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies` into my eclipse so they can be imported in my class.

I've got the Alfresco sourcecode already, but the tutorial at http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_on_Eclipse is very very short and doesn't seem to do it.

Anyone know a good, clear and working tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to be familar with Java & Eclipse.
Here is a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html

A certain amount of time would be needed. Afterwards you should be able to do your first Alfresco-Java steps.

Comment: Hey alfrescian, thank you yet again! You've been really helpful two times now! I think I found what I needed under 21.projectdependency in that article! I know the basics of java but I learned them with a BlueJ course which is a much simpler IDE compared to Eclipse, things like packaging and depending on other projects was never covered well, BlueJ felt like boom jarfile :p

Comment: Eclipse does have one remark tho, it tells me ` public setNodeService(NodeService nodeService){
     this.nodeService = nodeService;  
  }` as you showed me in [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136946/reading-the-value-of-a-document-property-from-within-a-behavior) has remark "return type for the method is missing" what do I do about that? it's the last remark left. (with all the dependencies there now, all the rest seems perfect)

Comment: it should be public void setNodeService ... as a setter should always return void ;-)
it's not eclipse who complains, it's the java compiler that  is automatically triggered within Eclipse.

Comment: oh god silly me, I didn't even think about it not having a return xD I should get more sleep. I'll inquire for a befriended acc to upvote you as well for the help!